# What is the scope of HTML custom element names?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

I am learning about HTML Web Components.  I understand that custom elements are registered via window.customElements.define() method.  And can optionally attach a shadow DOM.

My question is, do custom elements share a global scope, in a similar way as global variables?  The reference to the window object makes it appear so.  Or can they be scoped to a shadow DOM.

If it's a global scope, how would one avoid conflicts between custom element names?  Say a local `<super-button>` vs library 1's `<super-button>` vs library 2's `<super-button>`.  Thanks for guidance.

Comment: At the moment there is one Global Registry; separate registries are being discussed; see https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues

Comment: Specifically https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/716

Answer (score 2):

Global scope according to the `NotSupportedError` [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#exceptions)

> The CustomElementRegistry already contains an entry with the same name
> or the same constructor (or is otherwise already defined), or extends
> is specified and it is a valid custom element name, or extends is
> specified but the element it is trying to extend is an unknown
> element.

Best way to avoid conflicts is to practice namespacing - all your components will start with `mycustomprefix-component-name`.

[Naming web components](https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/how-should-i-name-my-element) also suggests using a namespace.

Comment: Depends on what you are creating; if you create a ``<svg-icon>`` then you shouldn't care about naming conflicts, everyone should just use your **'the best'** component. If you are creating a Design System, then a good prefix is part of your marketing.